# console.log browser in android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, console.log

How to see `console.log` messages of a website using android emulator?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From Rich Chetwynd's short article "Javascript debugging on Android browser".

> You can log javascript errors and console messages from your Android device or emulator. To do this you first need to install the Android SDK and USB drivers and enable USB debugging on the actual device.
>
> To check if the device is connected correctly you can run the following cmd from your Android SDK tools directory and you should see a device in the list
>
> `c:\android sdk..\platform-tools\adb devices`
>
> You can then use the Android Debug Bridge to filter debug messages so that you only see browser related messages by running the following cmd.
>
> `c:\android sdk..\platform-tools\adb logcat browser:V *:S`
>
> By default the log is written to stdout so you will see any Javascript errors or console.log messages etc written to the cmd window.

Further details: [Logcat CLI tool docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html).

Comment: I see - `running logcat browser:V *:S` seems to output all logs for me, I had to pipe it to grep to get relevant logs.

Comment: Under linux box: `cd ~/eclipse/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools; ./adb logcat browser:V *:S | sed 's/^.*Console: \(.*\) [^ ]*/\1/'`

Comment: I had to use `adb logcat chromium:V *:S` on API 21

Comment: `zsh: no matches found: *:S`

Comment: I added a command to get the log from the emulator at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 7):

If you have started the emulator from `Eclipse` with the `ADT plugin`, you will see all `JavaScript` console logs directly under the LogCat view :

```
Window -> Show View -> Android -> LogCat
```

Answer (score 7):

Open this url on your chrome

chrome://inspect

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Android Studio; you can open your Logcat (Alt+6) and filter for: `:CONSOLE`

Filtering for only `:CONSOLE` (rather than `INFO:CONSOLE`) will display all types of console messages (including ERROR, WARN, etc).

Answer (score 4):

You could add some JavaScript temporarily like...

```
var console = {
    log: function(msg) { alert(msg); }
};
```

Ugly as hell, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I hijacked the console.log using this code:

```
function logManager() {
    var self = this;

    self.init = function () {
        console.log('logmanager initialized');
        var old = console.log;
        self.logger = document.getElementById('log');
        console.log = function (message, options) {
            if (typeof message == 'object') {
                self.logger.innerHTML = (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(message) : message) + '<br />' + self.logger.innerHTML;
            } else {
                self.logger.innerHTML = message + '<br />' + self.logger.innerHTML;
            }
        }
    }
    self.toggleLogVisibility = function () {
        return $(self.logger).toggle();
    };
}
```

And consume it like so in your html with your own styling (absolute top right is what I used)

```
<div id="log" class="log">
    Application loaded...
</div>
```

And in your jscript (run this on page loaded as the log element has to exist)

```
document.lmgr = new logManager();
document.lmgr.init();
```

Answer (score 2):

Command  - get log from the emulator

```
adb -e logcat
```

adb.exe can be found at $your_installation_path$\android sdk\platform-tools

more detailed
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot run `adb logcat browser:V *:S` because of zsh, you need to run `noglob adb logcat browser:V *:S`. Rationale: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/2901

Answer (score 0):

If you are running React native, then in VSC where you RAN it: npm start ... you can see LOG ... it will output what every you put into Console.log, alternatvely run it in the WEB, and regular console.log ... F12, in inspector... the usual web development...