# submitting a form on android using java script 

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, safari

I use the following `javascript` code to `validate/submit` my form:

```
function SendForm()  {
            var formlist = document.getElementById ("formlist");
            var buttonRadios = document.getElementsByName ("film");
            var selected = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < formationRadios.length; i++) {
                if (formationRadios[i].checked) {
                    selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (selected) {
                 document.formlist.submit ();

            }
            else {
           //nothing to do
            }            
        }
```

In the Html side:

```
<form  method="post" name="formlist"  action="films.php" OnChange="SendForm();">
...
<input type="radio" name="film" id="spman" value="spman" required="required"><label for="spman">Spider Man</label>
...

<select class="required" name="date" id="date">
<option selected value="13-05-2012">13 May 2012</option>
...
</select>
</form>
```

***This works with firefox beta under android but not with the android default browser***. It also works with  firefox desktop browser.

Could you tell me what's wrong with it, I don't have errors inf firebug console.

Update:

I finally found the problem, it doesn't come from the code but from the iPhone/iPad bug with checking radio box when clicking label, for further information:

http://v4.thewatchmakerproject.com/blog/how-to-fix-the-broken-ipad-form-label-click-issue/

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957055/console-log-browser-in-android-emulator This will tell you how to debug Android Browser for javascript errors. If you get the error message, update your question then we'll try to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 2.2 the built-in browser doesn't support the access of forms through the `document` object (Like `document.name_of_your_form.submit()`). Try one of the following possibilities:

`id` attribute:

HTML

```
<form id="formlist">
```

JavaScript

```
var formlist = document.getElementById("formlist");
```

`name` attribute

HTML

```
<form name="formlist">
```

JavaScript

```
var formlist = document.forms["formlist"];
```

or

```
var formlist = document.formlist;
```

Comment: I tried both solutions, they work fine on firefox on my desktop withour error, but in android default browser form is not sumbmitted :/

Comment: Are you doing this inside an android App (WebView)? Or just as a regular website. And a very stupid question: Is JavaScript maybe turned off on your Android device by any chance?

Comment: Thanks, It is inside a website and javascript is enabled :/ I also activated console under via about:config method, I d'ont understand what is happening !

Comment: Well the `id` was definitely one problem and your original method of access doesn't Work since Android 2.2. Could you try putting an `alert()` in your `SendForm()` function and see if it shows up on Android?

Comment: I added an alert msg in the SendForm() function
Firefox mobile : ok
Firefox Desktop : ok
Android Built in browser: KO

Comment: Then the Android browser doesn't support the `onchange` event for forms. I'm actually surprised that it works anywhere, as I've never heard of it before. Try setting up the events on your `input` fields.